# multipile inheritance logic in C++

Tags: c++, inheritance

Say I have a function f=sigma(phi(x)), where I want to assign different forms for the function sigma and phi.Let's say we have two sigma functions and two phi function so we have 4=2*2 combinations. How could I achieve this?

If only for f=sigma(x), I write sigma as a virtual function in f and define the specific forms of sigma as subclass.

```
class sigma1: public class f{sigma=sigma1}

class sigma2: public class f{sigma=sigma2}
```

But when phi is involved, I get really confused. I suppose again I need to define phi as virtual function. But then for a specific phi, does it should be

```
class phi1 : public sigma1, public sigma 2

class phi2 : public sigma1, public sigma 2
```

Say I want to create an object sigma1+phi1. How could I do this? If I simply write

```
phi1 object1
```

then clearly it won't able to know to use sigma1 or sigma2. Virtual inheritance also does not seem to work. I know that I could create four class like

```
class phi1 : public sigma1 {phi=phi1}

class phi2 : public sigma2 {phi=phi1}

class phi3 : public sigma1 {phi=phi2}

class phi4 : public sigma2 {phi=phi2}
```

But this does not seem to be smart....

Comment: Could you give us a real code sample, ideally a [MCVE] please.

Answer (score 0):

Isn't clear, to me, how do you intend to use your class (or function, or what do you want), but I propose you the following simple solution that is based on the hypothesis that your phi() and sigma() functions are functions receiving a variable of type `T` and returning a value of the same type `T`.

So I've constructed a templated functor that receive the type `T` and the function `Sigma` and `Phi` as arguments

```
template <typename T, T (*Sigma)(const T &), T (*Phi)(const T &)>
struct f
 {
   T operator() (const int & x) const
    { return Sigma(Phi(x)); }
 };
```

The following is a full example with sigma() and phi() function receiving `int` and returning `int`

```
#include <iostream>

int sigma1 (const int & x)
 { return x+1; }

int sigma2 (const int & x)
 { return x-1; }

int phi1 (const int & x)
 { return x+10; }

int phi2 (const int & x)
 { return x-10; }


template <typename T, T (*Sigma)(const T &), T (*Phi)(const T &)>
struct f
 {
   T operator() (const int &x) const
    { return Sigma(Phi(x)); }
 };


int main ()
 { 
   f<int, sigma1, phi1>  f11;
   f<int, sigma1, phi2>  f12;
   f<int, sigma2, phi1>  f21;
   f<int, sigma2, phi2>  f22;

   std::cout << "f11(100) = " << f11(100) << std::endl;
   std::cout << "f12(100) = " << f12(100) << std::endl;
   std::cout << "f21(100) = " << f21(100) << std::endl;
   std::cout << "f22(100) = " << f22(100) << std::endl;

   return 0;
 }
```

Other solutions are possible; by example, you can write a templated function instead a templated functor.

But, I repeat: isn't clear, to me, what do you want to obtain.

p.s.: sorry for my bad English